# why the function isnt detect that the variable the_greater_list as list

Tags: python

Why the function `is_greater` doesn't detect the variable `the_greater_list` as a `list` type of variable and class it as none.

```
def is_greater(my_list, n):
  """the function check wich numbers in my list greater than n.
  :param my_list: the list.
  :param n: the cut from nubers than greater to number than smaller.
  :type my_list: list.
  :type n: int.
  :return: the_greater_list.
  :retype: list.
  """
  list(the_greater_list = [])
  for number in my_list:
      if number >= n:
          the_greater_list = the_greater_list.append(number)
  return the_greater_list

list1 = [1, 30, 25, 60, 27, 28]
N = 28
print(is_greater(list1, N))
```

what I need to do that make python to class `the_greater_list` as `list` type of variable?

Comment: What is `list(the_greater_list = [])` supposed to do? That's invalid syntax. I think you just mean `the_greater_list = []` without `list()` around it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `list(the_greater_list = [])` is incorrect. You define an empty list by doing `the_greater_list = []`. Then, doing `the_greater_list.append(number)` returns a `None`, so when you do `the_greater_list = the_greater_list.append(number)`, it makes `the_greater_list` as `None`

```
def is_greater(my_list, n):
    the_greater_list = []
    for number in my_list:
        if number >= n:
            the_greater_list.append(number)
    return the_greater_list
list1 = [1, 30, 25, 60, 27, 28]
N = 28
print(is_greater(list1, N))
```

The easier way would be to use list comprehension instead, as pointed out by Matthias in the comment below.

Comment: It's not invalid syntax, it's a type error.

Comment: With a list comprehension the full function body can be written in one line: `return [number for number in my_list if number >= n]`

Comment: @Matthias Yes, I know that. I just wanted to show the OP the mistake in his code.

Comment: @Matthias The questions wasn't "How to improve the code"

Comment: @some_programmer I should have made clear that this is just for future reference. I would have written the same code in the answer as you did.

Comment: if i write just '''the_greater_list''' without list so it write to me "'nonetype' object has no atributte 'append'"

Comment: @matthias it work with your code, why it isn't work with my code, because it still write me that the list is an object 'nonetype', why it written it to me

Comment: @neriya The code in this answer works. I assume you still have `the_greater_list = the_greater_list.append(number)` in your code.

Comment: @matthias I still have  the_greater_list = the_greater_list.append(number), but the python file isn't recognize it as type list but as nonetype argument. how I solve this problem?

Comment: You didn't read the answer completely. `append` mutates the list it is called on, it doesn't give back a list. `append` returns `None`, so if you do `the_greater_list = the_greater_list.append(number)` then `the_greater_list` will be `None` afterwards. Do a simple: `the_greater_list.append(number)`